# How get the value of a cell in a selected row (shiny DT library)

Tags: r, shiny, dt

i trying print the value of a cell in selected row.

This is datatanle code in **ui.R**

```
body <- dashboardBody(
    tabItems(#Contenido de las pestañas
        tabItem(#Pestaña para consultas
            tabName = "consulta",
            DT::dataTableOutput("tablaConsulta"),
            textOutput("consultaSelecionada")
        )
)
```

And this the code in **server.R**

```
output$tablaConsulta <- DT::renderDataTable({#Tabla consultas
    library(RODBC)
    nombre_data <- "consulta.rds"##Nombre archivo
    if(file.exists(nombre_data)){##Si existe el archivo
        consulta<- readRDS(nombre_data)## Recojemos los datos desde el archivo
    }else{##Si no existe el archivo
        # Nos conectamos a la base de datos
        conn <- odbcConnect("ORAC11.ORACLE11G", uid="l21", pwd="l21", rows_at_time = 500, believeNRows=FALSE)
        sql <- "select COCODIGO, COTEXTO,COCOSE,COCOPS,COFECHA from L2113T00"
        #Ejecutamos la query
        consulta <- sqlQuery(conn,sql) 
        close(conn)
        #La guardamos en el archivo
        saveRDS(consulta,nombre_data)
    }
})
```

This code output "consultas" datatable, its fine. The problem, i need print "COCODIGO" in textOuput.

I try do this:

```
output$consultaSelecionada <- renderPrint({
    s = input$tablaConsulta_rows_selected
    cat("Consultas selecionadas")
    cat(s,sep=", ")
})
```

This print the selected row number, i need print the selected row "COCODIGO" value.

How i can do that?

Comment: you could do `consulta[s,"COCODIGO"]` to get the value at the selected row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take the creation of the table outside the rendering function. Doing so will improve both rendering time and maintainability.
It will also let the `consulta` object available in the (shiny's) global environment.
Do you can then  use it to subset:

#### server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(RODBC)

function(input, output) {
    
    nombre_data <- "consulta.rds"##Nombre archivo
    
    if(file.exists(nombre_data)){ ##Si existe el archivo
        consulta<- readRDS(nombre_data) ## Recojemos los datos desde el archivo
          } else { ##Si no existe el archivo
          # Nos conectamos a la base de datos
          conn <- odbcConnect("ORAC11.ORACLE11G", 
                              uid="l21", 
                              pwd="l21", 
                              rows_at_time = 500, 
                              believeNRows=FALSE)
        sql <- "select COCODIGO, COTEXTO,COCOSE,COCOPS,COFECHA from L2113T00"
        #Ejecutamos la query
        consulta <- sqlQuery(conn,sql, stringsAsFactor = F) 
        close(conn)
        #La guardamos en el archivo
        saveRDS(consulta,nombre_data)
    }
    
    output$tablaConsulta <- DT::renderDataTable({consulta
        
        
    })
    
    output$consultaSelecionada <- renderText({
        s = input$tablaConsulta_rows_selected
        consulta[s, 'COCODIGO']
    })
}
```